# Написать unit тест с заглушками на любой из методов

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

Необходимо написать unit тест
с заглушками на любой из методов.

```
using System;

namespace Cinema
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Playbill playbill = new Playbill();

            // 1. Вывод сеансов
            playbill.PrintMovies();

            // 2. Ввод пользователем сеанса
            DateTime dt;
            Console.WriteLine("Введите дату:");
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out dt))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Не верный формат даты. Нажмите что-нибудь для выхода...");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Введите название фильма:");
            string filmname = Console.ReadLine();

            Movie mov;
            if ((mov = playbill.SearchMovie(dt, filmname)) == null)
            {
            }

            // 3.1 Вывод свободных мест в кинозале
            mov.PrintFreePlaces();

            int answ;
            // 3.2 Выбор места
            Console.WriteLine("Количество билетов: ");
            if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out answ))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Не верный формат данных. Нажмите что-нибудь для выхода...");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
                return;
            }

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

    // стуктруа "Место"
    struct Place
    {
        public int row;// ряд
        public int place_number;// номер сиденья
        public Place(int r, int p)
        {
            row = r;
            place_number = p;
        }
    }

    // класс "Сеанс"
    class Movie
    {
        public readonly DateTime datetime;// дата сеанса
        public readonly string name;
        public readonly int price;
        public readonly string genre;
        public readonly TimeSpan duration;// продолжительность сеанса
        public Place[] free_places;
        public int free_pl_count;// кол-во свободных мест

        private static readonly int fr_pl_MAX_cnt = 100;
        private static readonly int rows_MAX_cnt = 10;

        private static Random random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        public Movie(DateTime datetime, string name, int price, string genre, TimeSpan duration)
        {
            this.datetime = datetime;
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
            this.genre = genre;
            this.duration = duration;

            free_pl_count = random.Next(1, fr_pl_MAX_cnt);
            GenerateFreePlaces();
        }
        private void GenerateFreePlaces()
        {
            // рандомное генерирование свободных мест
            free_places = new Place[random.Next(1, rows_MAX_cnt)];
            for (int i = 0; i < free_places.Length; i++)
                free_places[i] = new Place(random.Next(0, rows_MAX_cnt), random.Next(0, fr_pl_MAX_cnt));
        }
        public bool CheckForPlace(int row, int pnumber)
        {
            foreach (Place p in free_places)
                if (row == p.row && pnumber == p.place_number)
                    return true;
            return false;
        }
        public void PrintFreePlaces()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Количество свободных мест | Ряд | Места");
            Console.WriteLine(free_pl_count);
            foreach (Place p in free_places)
                Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t     {0}\t  {1}", p.row, p.place_number);
        }
    }

    // класс "Киноафиша"
    class Playbill
    {
        public Movie[] movies;
        public Playbill()
        {
            movies = new Movie[3];
            movies[0] = new Movie(new DateTime(2018, 01, 12, 14, 00, 00), "Матрица", 19, "Фантастика", new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0));
            movies[1] = new Movie(new DateTime(2018, 01, 15, 19, 00, 00), "Елеки", 13, "Фантастика", new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
            movies[2] = new Movie(new DateTime(2018, 01, 24, 09, 00, 00), "Небо", 11, "Фантастика", new TimeSpan(1, 30, 0));

        }
        public Movie SearchMovie(DateTime date, string name)
        {
            // поиск сеанса с заданной датой и названием
            foreach (Movie m in movies)
                if (m.datetime.Date == date && m.name == name)
                    return m;
                else
                    continue;

            return null;
        }
        public void PrintMovies()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  Дата\t  |\tВремя | Название фильма | Стоимость билета |\t Жанр\t   | Время сеанса");
            foreach (Movie m in movies)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1:d2}:{2:d2}\t{3}\t\t\t{4}р.\t\t{5}\t{6} мин.", m.datetime.Date.ToShortDateString(),
                                       m.datetime.Hour, m.datetime.Minute, m.name, m.price, m.genre, m.duration.TotalMinutes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Какие попытки написания тестов предпринимались?

Comment: @Tarasovych вот https://yadi.sk/i/k7pvt3qW3Rvq7A дальше не смог. не осилил. если поможет буду рад...

Comment: пожалуйста, не задавайте один и тот же вопрос несколько раз. если хотите добавить деталей или пример кода - исправьте уже существующий пост

Comment: "...unit тест с заглушками на любой из методов..." что подразумевается под "заглушками"? Unit тесты пишут чтобы проверить работу конкретного метода при разных исходных данных. Неразумно писать "универсальные" тесты, в таком случае весь смысл TDD разработки превращается в бессмысленную трату времени и сил.

Comment: А можете подсказать, что это такое? Movie [] movies = new Movie SearchMovie[4];

Comment: @test123 рандомный набор символов)))

Comment: @yolosora я пытался написать. как сумел. да выходит не доделал.

Comment: @tym32167 мне надо Movie SearchMovie а там такого нет

Comment: Но кланы то зачем делать? У вас же есть аккаунт уже, пользуйтесь им

Comment: @yolosora, фух, я уж было подумал что что-то в шарпе поменялось. >> мне надо Movie SearchMovie<< Нет, вам это не надо. Вы сами сделали Movie вместо Movie[] у метода поиска. Меняйте шапку метода.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Перво-наперво класс `Playbill` надо сделать `public`.
Затем прав.клик на любой строке этого класса, выбираем пункт создания тестового проекта

[image: выбор в меню]

В этом окне можно ничего не менять, просто жмём ОК

[image: след. окно создания тестового проекта]

После создания проекта, откроем окно с помощью которого можно работать с запуском, остановкой, проверкой тестов

[image: открытие окна тестов]

Теперь в этом окне можно запускать на проверку тесты и смотреть результаты

[image: окно управления тестами]

Собственно вот начало тестирования. Фактически сделан только один тест вашего метода, на успешный поиск с правильными данными. Далее пишите по аналогии свои тесты, метод нужно еще протестировать на поиск с ошибочной датой и отдельный тест на поиск с ошибочным названием фильма, это как минимум.

```
[TestClass()]
public class PlaybillTests
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public void PlaybillTest()
    {
        Playbill playbill = new Playbill();

        Assert.IsNotNull(playbill);
        Assert.IsTrue(playbill.movies.Count() > 0);
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void SearchMovieSuccessTest() //проверка успешного поиска
    {
        //Arrange (подготовка)
        string name = "Небо";
        DateTime date = new DateTime(2018, 01, 24, 09, 00, 00);
        Playbill playbill = new Playbill();

        //Act (выполнение)
        Movie result = playbill.SearchMovie(date, name);

        //Assert (проверка)
        Assert.IsNotNull(result); //проверка что результат не null, т.е. результат получен
        Assert.AreEqual(name, result.name); //проверка что имена совпадают
        Assert.AreEqual(date, result.datetime); //проверка что даты совпадают

        //!Кстати этот тест выявляет ошибку в проверяемом методе
        //у вас написано if (m.datetime.Date == date && m.name == name)
        //а должно быть if (m.datetime == date && m.name == name)
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void PrintMoviesTest()
    {
        Assert.Fail();
    }
}
```

Comment: большое вам спасибо

Comment: @user286794 Пожалуйста, только на будущее, не надо плодить аккаунты под один  и тот же вопрос, и бомбардировать с помощью них одним и тем же вопросом, хорошо?

Comment: хорошо, больше такого не повториться. обещаю. спасибо, что выручили меня эхх если бы не вы то...